# How to replace the last element in a vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure

As a newbie to Clojure I often have difficulties to express the simplest things. For example, for replacing the last element in a vector, which would be

```
v[-1]=new_value
```

in python, I end up with the following variants in Clojure:

```
(assoc v (dec (count v)) new_value)
```

which is pretty long and inexpressive to say the least, or

```
(conj (vec (butlast v)) new_value)
```

which even worse, as it has `O(n)` running time.

That leaves me feeling silly, like a caveman trying to repair a Swiss watch with a club.

What is the right Clojure way to replace the last element in a vector?

---

To support my `O(n)`-claim for `butlast`-version (Clojure 1.8):

```
(def v (vec (range 1e6)))
#'user/v
user=> (time (first (conj (vec (butlast v)) 55)))
"Elapsed time: 232.686159 msecs"
0
(def v (vec (range 1e7)))
#'user/v
user=> (time (first (conj (vec (butlast v)) 55)))
"Elapsed time: 2423.828127 msecs"
0
```

So basically for 10 time the number of elements it is 10 times slower.

Comment: Your first way would be how it's done. Obviously, you could write a "replace-last" function to clean it up. I think Python's overly succinct way of expressing that has spoiled your expectations unfortunately. I don't think indexing from the rear is needed often enough to warrent its own syntax in Clojure. +1 because I'd like to be proven wrong.

Comment: Note:  solution #3 is not O(n) if `v` is already a vector (I recommend always using a Clojure vector over a Clojure list as the default choice, unless measurement proves otherwise).

Comment: This is a well-delimited, specific question and answer, but I think it's worth pointing out that many algorithms expressed with index expressions in Python have an idiomatic Clojure equivalent that does not require using indexes.

Comment: @AlanThompson my measurements imply that it is `O(n)`, please see my edit.

Comment: @AlanThompson The [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L272) for `butlast` shows that it is order of `(count coll)` for sequence `coll`, as OP suggests.

Comment: You are correct that the source code loops over all items in the sequence. I had assumed that a vector arg would use structural sharing to make it O(log32 n).  Doh!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd use

```
(defn set-top [coll x]
  (conj (pop coll) x))
```

For example,

```
(set-top [1 2 3] :a)
=> [1 2 :a]
```

But it also works on the *front* of lists:

```
(set-top '(1 2 3) :a)
=> (:a 2 3)
```

The Clojure stack functions - `peek`, `pop`, and `conj` - work on the natural open end of a sequential collection.

But there is no one right way.

---

How do the various solutions react to an empty vector?

- Your Python `v[-1]=new_value` throws an exception, as does your `(assoc v (dec (count v)) new_value)` and my `(defn set-top [coll x] (conj (pop coll) x))`.
- Your `(conj (vec (butlast v)) new_value)` returns `[new_value]`. The `butlast` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on being "pure", your 2nd or 3rd solutions will work.  I prefer to be simpler & more explicit using the helper functions [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#replacing-values-in-a-sequence):

```
(s/defn replace-at :- ts/List
  "Replaces an element in a collection at the specified index."
  [coll     :- ts/List
   index    :- s/Int
   elem     :- s/Any]
   ...)

(is (= [9 1 2] (replace-at (range 3) 0 9)))
(is (= [0 9 2] (replace-at (range 3) 1 9)))
(is (= [0 1 9] (replace-at (range 3) 2 9)))
As with drop-at, replace-at will throw an exception for invalid values of index.
```

Similar helper functions exist for

- insert-at
- drop-at
- prepend
- append

Note that all of the above work equally well for either a Clojure list (eager or lazy) or a Clojure vector. [The `conj` solution will fail](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#adding-values-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-a-sequence) unless you are careful to always coerce the input to a vector first as in your example.

Comment: and what is the gain compared with `assoc`?